# Powershell Date error when loading data into datatable

Tags: mysql, powershell, date, odbc

I connect to a ODBC DSN to collect data from a COBOL database which works for most of the tables.
Now I've a problem with a table that has "wrong" dates in some columns. The date is 0000-00-00 which doesn't seems to be allowed in powershell datatable.

Does anyone know away around this problem? since the original data cannot be changed.

The code:

```
$conn = New-Object Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$conn.ConnectionString= "dsn=DSN_name;uid=;pwd=;"
$conn.open()


$result = (new-Object Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * from 'TaBLE_name';",$conn)).ExecuteReader()
$tableresult = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
try {
        $tableresult.load($result)
} 
Catch {
    Write-Host "ERROR : Unable to run: `n$Error[0]"
}
Finally {
    $conn.close()
}
```

The error:
`ERROR : Unable to run:  Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime."[0]`
The goal in the end is to write the $tableresult to an Mysql Database.

Comment: What database engine and/or odbc driver are you using?

Comment: The transoft ODBC driver 32bit and this works fine, seems to be the loading into Datatable that expects a date. I think powershell date doesn;t allow an invalid date.

Comment: It's not specific to PowerShell, it's the `[datetime]` type that doesn't support instantiating a new value with 0 as month or day. Wondering if you can somehow trick `DataTable.Load()` into not treating the values as datetime, but just strings, but I'm not sure how

Comment: Could not find a "trick" option. Issue is there are a 1000 tables with a lot of rows per table. This means some work now and some doesn't.